# Allow comments but no posts on my Facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I would like to allow people to comment on my posts on my timeline (since I post a lot of articles and things that I read, and enjoy discussing them), but I also want to prevent people from posting their own links/messages directly onto my timeline.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Go into *Privacy Settings* → *Timeline and Tagging | Edit Settings* and set **Who can post in your Timeline?** to the appropriate value.

Comment: Um that answer only gives the options of friends and me to allow to post. . .

Comment: @Shanah If I am correct those are the **only** options for choosing who can post on your timeline